# Callback for 4 asynchronous methods C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asynccallback

I have 4 asynchronous methods that perform at startup of my application.

I need to execute a final line of code, once ALL methods have finished. Because they are all executing asynchronously, how do I create a callback for determining when the last method has finished executing?

I thought about declaring a global counter variable, and incrementing it each time a method finishes, and once the counter reaches 4 the final line would execute.

But I thought this would be complicating it a bit, is there a simpler way of doing it?

```
    public async Task PerformStartupTasksAsync()
    {
        await CreateSmartsheet();

        // RUN THESE 4 ASYNCHRONOUSLY

        ImportMainDatabase();
        ImportIncomingSurveyResponse();
        ImportOutgoingSurveyResponse();
        UpdateHouseHoldListDropdown();

        // ENABLE CONTROLS HERE, AFTER 4 METHODS HAVE COMPLETED

    }
```

Comment: What are the signatures for the 4 methods? Are they `async`?

Comment: How do those four methods execute asynchronously? Do they use and return `Task`s? Do they explicitly spawn threads? Do they enqueue to the ThreadPool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you implement async invocation using TPL async model: return Task or Task for everything runs asynchronously. Then you can just use next line of code:

```
await Task.WhenAll(new [] {First, Second, Third, etc.});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460705(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => ImportMainDatabase(),
    () => ImportIncomingSurveyResponse(),
    () => ImportOutgoingSurveyResponse(),
    () => UpdateHouseHoldListDropdown()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If those 4 methods are synchronous, you don't need to do anything. They will run serially.

If they're async and they should run serially, then await them.

If they're async and they can run simultaneously, then capture the resulting tasks and use `Task.WhenAll` to continue when they all complete.